# What is $O\left({n}\choose{k} \right)$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Consider some ${n}\choose{k}$ where $k<n$. Could be for example ${n}\choose{n/2}$.

Is it true to say that for every such ${n}\choose{k}$ there's a $c\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$O\left({n}\choose{k}\right) = O(n^c)$$

In other words, asymptotically, are binomial coefficients bounded by some polynomial?

Comment: $\binom{2n}{n}>\frac{4^n}{2n+1}$, so no.

Comment: "Yes if $k$ is constant, no otherwise."

Comment: I see. Thank you all!

Comment: When you say something about $O$, you also need to say something like "as $n \to \infty$".

Comment: @GEdgar, alright, that's actually what I meant. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constant $k$,

$$\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}<\frac{n^k}{k!}=O(n^k)$$ which is polynomial in $n$.

But if you allow $k$ to vary with $n$, no.